# getting 'UnsupportedAuthorityValidation' error in react while using react-azure-adb2c library

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-b2c

I'm using this code to authenticate and to get access token using azure adb2c. And i'm using 'react-azure-adb2c' msal library.
i tried using (https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/) instance value as well.

```
import b2cauth from 'react-azure-adb2c';
b2cauth.initialize({
  instance: 'https://MyPortaldemo.b2clogin.com/tfp/', 
  tenant: '4f7d3971-9a3b-4a58-9342-ab0ffc4b842a',
  signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_signupsigninmydemoapp',   
  applicationId: 'ad8597bc-484b-495e-b968-ce91b60c4947',
  cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  scopes: ['https://MyPortaldemo.onmicrosoft.com/apireact/user_impersonation','openid'],
  //redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
});
b2cauth.run(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  serviceWorker.unregister();
});

and i'm getting this error
```

Comment: Could you try specifying `tenant: 'MyPortaldemo.onmicrosoft.com'`?

Comment: Thanks juunas.. i tried that as well. getting the same error

Comment: Hmm, when you registered the app, did you create it through B2C app registrations? Or if you created it through app registrations (Preview), did you select the option that allows B2C users to login?

Comment: I created through B2C app registration. and i dont find anything specific to select 'allows B2C users'

Comment: When do you get the error? Before or after entering the credentials? Be more precise on your observation.

Comment: Issue resolved. Thank you everyone. The problem is with msal javascript library. from december 2019 microsoft decommisioned 'login.microsoftonline.com' and changed the url to '{tenant}.b2clogin.com'. But inside msal library, still old url's were referred. It's a problem with the package.

Comment: If the issue was resolved, please post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Summarize your comment as answer to help others who have the same problem.

> When you set up an identity provider for sign-up and sign-in in your Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C) application, you need to specify a redirect URL. You should no longer reference login.microsoftonline.com in your applications and APIs. Instead, **use `b2clogin.com` for all new applications, and migrate existing applications from `login.microsoftonline.com` to `b2clogin.com`**.

The **deprecation** of `login.microsoftonline.com` goes into effect for all Azure AD B2C tenants on 04 December 2020, providing existing tenants one year to migrate to `b2clogin.com`. **New tenants created after 04 December 2019 will not accept requests from `login.microsoftonline.com`.** All functionality remains the same on the `b2clogin.com` endpoint.

For more details, you could refer to this article about [migrating applications and apis to  b2clogin.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin).