# ReactJS frontend with Azure AD B2C error UnsupportedAuthorityValidation

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a problem with this, I use ReactJS frontend with Azure AD B2C, but when I run react
displays this error "Uncaught (in promise) UnsupportedAuthorityValidation" I still don't understand why

```
import b2cauth from 'react-azure-adb2c';


b2cauth.initialize({
  instance: 'https://FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com/tfp/', 
  tenant: 'FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com',
  signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_ADB2C_API',
  applicationId: 'ae82c7fe-a82b-448d-905f-6a63827e92a4',
  cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  scopes: ['https://FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com/teastAPI/user_impersonation'],
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
});


b2cauth.run(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  serviceWorker.unregister();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of your library, this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61453943/getting-unsupportedauthorityvalidation-error-in-react-while-using-react-azure) will help you.

1. Use `{your-tenant-name}.b2clogin.com` instead of `login.microsoftonline.com`.
2. If you're using MSAL.NET v2 or earlier, set the **ValidateAuthority** property to `false`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin#validateauthority-property).

Comment: b2cauth.initialize({
  instance: 'https://FunSuitDev.b2clogin.com/tfp/', 
  tenant: 'FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com',
  signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_ADB2C_API',
  applicationId: '21f61ee6-00b3-4be0-b3c3-f7597136c7b3',
  cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  validateAuthority: false,
  scopes: ['https://FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com/teastAPI/user_impersonation'],
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
});

the result is still the same. still error

Comment: @Ariffadhillah `validateAuthority` is used like this code:`this.clientApplication = new UserAgentApplication(
  env.auth.clientId,
  env.auth.loginAuthority,
  this.authCallback.bind(this),
  {
    validateAuthority: false
  }
);`. It's not in the b2cauth.initialize.

Comment: but I saw from this tutorial that
https://medium.com/@fiqriismail/how-to-secure-your-reactjs-frontend-with-azure-ad-b2c-8fd165f602e8
he does not use "validateAuthority" and there is no "UnsupportedAuthorityValidation" error and if I try to use the code in the tutorial everything works fine, but when I use Azure's my id
"example: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/', tenant:,
signInPolicy:,
applicationId:,
cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
scope :,
redirectUri: 'http: // localhost: 3000', "
everything becomes an error "UnsupportedAuthorityValidation"

Comment: @Ariffadhillah Do you mean that if you use code like this: `b2cauth.initialize({
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/', 
  tenant: 'peachitad.onmicrosoft.com',
  signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_react_signup',
  applicationId: '702f55a3-72fd-4da1-a22b-1dc82e70a049',
  cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  scopes: ['https://peachitad.onmicrosoft.com/api/user_impersonation'],
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
});`, everything works well?

Comment: if i use my Azure id it won't run

b2cauth.initialize ({
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/',
  tenant: 'FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com',
  signInPolicy: 'B2C_1_teas_API',
  applicationId: '38b037ae-c64f-4f43-a5c9-4234c31d5199',
  cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
  scopes: ['https://FunSuitDev.onmicrosoft.com/testapi/user_impersonation'],
  redirectUri: 'http: // localhost: 3000 /',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
});

Comment: are there any other settings, which need to be added again to azure?

Comment: Do you try to set the `ValidateAuthority` property to *false*?